# Complexity of the regular module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra with a module $M$ who has minimal injective coresolution $(I_i)$. Define the complexity $cx(M)$ as $cx(M):= \inf \{ t \geq 0 | \dim(I_i) \leq a i^{t-1}$ for all $i \geq n_0$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and some $a \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

> Question: Do we have $cx(_AA)=cx(A_{A})$?

Note $cx(M)=0$ iff $M$ has finite injective dimension so this question should contain the Gorenstein symmetry conjecture $(id(A)< \inf$ if and only if $id(A^{op}) < \inf )$ as a special case.

I wonder whether this question has been considered before. Looking at some random algebras gave me the feeling that it might be true (of course I might just look at the wrong random algebras and I can only look at a small number of terms of the injective coresolution with the computer).